# Automatically restart hive-server2 if client cannot connect

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have some hadoop clusters that from time to time stop accepting client connections.  Appears to be memory related issues.   When hive-server2 is restarted, they can connect again.

Some memory turning has made it so this problem does not occur as often.

I'd like an automated method (a script scheduled via cron, or a loop with sleep....) that periodically checks if hive is accepting connections and if not, just restart the service.

I tried testing netstat -an | grep 10000 result, but sometimes it returns listeners, even when clients cannot connect.

My programming skills are minimal.  I know hadoop ok.  Am wondering if anyone has a suggestion that might work.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your cron restart the server periodically, e.g: every 24 hours. If you are willing to accept loss of server state (i.e. you only look at the query result, and not interested in the query history etc), you can just restart periodically.